# Scheme in EntityFrameworkModel that doesn't exist in the MySQL database itself

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework

I have run into a weird issue that I have never seen before. I tried to search around Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find any related issues whatsoever.

The problem:
I am developing a .NET Framework WPF application to import data from excel sheets into a MySQL database hosted on a Apache Webserver on some Virtual Machine.
The application (written in C#) is accessing the database using EntityFramework 6 and the MySQL.Data / MySQL.Data.EntityFramework NuGet packages (Version v8.0.22).

I have no issues connection to the database both inside the application and the Visual Studio Server Explorer. However, whenever I try to read or write data to the database, I am running in the following exception:

[Table not found Exception][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZlxm.png

The database is apparently searching for the table SIMsaar.SIMsaar.KATEGORIE.
SIMsaar is the name of my database, KATEGORIE is the name of the dbTable. I don't know at all why there's a second SIMsaar between the dbName and dbTable.
I figured out yesterday, that the issue *might* be related to the EntityFramework. Here is a snippet of the code for dbTable KATEGORIE in the .edmx-File:

```
<EntityContainer Name="SIMsaarModelStoreContainer">
<EntitySet Name="KATEGORIE" EntityType="Self.KATEGORIE" Schema="SIMsaar" store:Type="Tables" />
```

As seen in the code above, the .edmx-File contains a Schema-Definition for the dbTable (it's the same for any table found in the EF-Model. I already tried to remove the Schema. This results in the application working properly, but if I try to update the model from the database, any classes contained by the model are getting removed by Visual Studio, essentially breaking the entire application.

Now to the actual question(s):

Why does the EntityFrameworkModel contain a schema? There is no such schema in the database (afaik MySQL doesn't support database schemas), I can access all tables over SIMsaar.dbTableName (using the Visual Studio Server Explorer + SQL-Script).

How can I remove the Schema from the EntityFrameworkModel without it breaking the entire application? As said before, I could just remove it from the .edmx-File, but that will eventually break when I need to update the database.

Is there a way to create a new EntityFrameworkModel without it creating the dbSchema?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you considered shelving or backing up what you have now and re scaffolding from the database? I just started using mysql. In mysql workbench i was initially a bit surprised to see it calls databases schemas.

Comment: I already tried this, but it just re-creates the Model with the exact same issue. It always adds a database scheme to the model, and then complains it can't find the database tables under the self-created name.
e.g The database is called SIMsaar, the table is called KATEGORIE. So naturally i would think it searches for SIMsaar.KATEGORIE, but it searches for SIMsaar.SIMsaar.Kategorie